# an example from pstricks manual, why the "linecolor" can not work

Tags: macros, pstricks, xkeyval

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-poly,pst-text,pst-key,graphicx,color}

\makeatletter

\SpecialCoor

\def\PstCoggedWheel#1#2{%
% #1 = number of teeth (it must be a divisor of 360!)
% #2 = height of the teeth, between 0 and 1 unit
\pst@cntc=360
\divide\pst@cntc by #1
\pst@cntd=\pst@cntc
\divide\pst@cntd\tw@
 \pst@dimd=\psunit
 \pssetlength{\pst@dimc}{#2}%
 \advance\pst@dimd-\pst@dimc
 \pscustom{%
 \moveto(\pst@dimd;0)
 \multido{\iAngleA=\z@+\pst@cntc,
 \iAngleB=\pst@cntd+\pst@cntc,
 \iAngleC=\pst@cntc+\pst@cntc}{#1}{%
 \lineto(1;\iAngleA)
 \lineto(1;\iAngleB)
 \lineto(\pst@dimd;\iAngleB)
 \lineto(\pst@dimd;\iAngleC)}}}




\makeatother

\begin{document}

\rput(-2,4){\PstCoggedWheel{9}{0.3}}
 \rput(-2,1){\PstCoggedWheel{9}{7mm}}
\rput(-2,-3){\psset{unit=2,linecolor=red}\PstCoggedWheel{40}{0.1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the compilation chokes already  at some earlier point. Are you sure you copied the full example code from `pstricks-doc.pdf`, page 186f?

Comment: I'm sure I have copied all the example code, page 193.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the loading of `pst-key`, and everything will run fine. I even compiled this directly with `pdflatex`, having loaded `auto-pst-pdf` *after* `pstricks` (don't forget to add the `--enable-write18` switch for the compiler (MiKTeX), or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pst-key` is an old package, use `pst-xkey` instead. However, use only `\usepackage{pstricks,multido}` and `\SpecialCoor` is no more needed, it is the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\makeatletter
\def\PstCoggedWheel#1#2{%
  [...]
```